# How to set a tooltip on a JavaFX Pane?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tooltip

Method setToolTip() can't be used for pane, but аll the same, it is possible? How I can set a tooltip on a JavaFX Pane? Or how to display a toolbox at the cursor position?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the static [`Tooltip.install(node, tooltip)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#install-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.control.Tooltip-) method to install a tooltip onto a node which does not possess a `node.setTooltip(tooltip)` method.

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.setPrefSize(100, 100);
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("This is a Pane");
Tooltip.install(pane, tooltip);
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me a lot))